# How do I get x and y coordinates to fit all kind of screen sizes

Tags: flutter, dart, math

I'm trying to make a tagging system like Instagram. But I met a problem, where the location of the tag isn't the same on all devices/screens, because of difference in size and height. How can i Accomplish the same tagging system as Instagram?

I have this code, where the tagging takes place:

```
GestureDetector(
                        onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) =>
                            _onTapDown(details, context),
                        child: Container(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 500,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                  image:
                                      AssetImage("assets/images/girl.jpg"))),
                        ),
                      )
```

And this function, where I Am finding the local x and y coordinates on the image.

```
_onTapDown(TapDownDetails details, context1) {
setState(() {
  posx = details.localPosition.dx;
  posy = details.localPosition.dy;
});
print(posx);
print(posy);
```

}

hope my problem is understandable, if not don't hesitate to ask about more information.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not aware of insta, Are you trying to tap on image and place icon/something on that point?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't declared how Instagram's tagging system is working. I'm trying to make a tagging system, which meaning when I'm touching a point on a image, there should come a dot or a little message at that point on the image. So the thing I want to accomplish, is that the point is located the same location on all kind of devices/screen.

Comment: while you are using localPosition it  seems ok and using `fit: BoxFit.fill` will depend on screen ratio

Comment: Which kind of formula should i use for that?

Comment: in this case, you using BoxFit height or width may provide perfect pixel point